# Hadoop I/O intensive examples

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking

I want to test my Hadoop I/O performance with several I/O intensive jobs. I know the benchmark  TestDFSIO is a good example. But I still wonder if there are any other good I/O intensive benchmark for Hadoop?

BTW, are there any CPU intensive benchmarks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wordcount is intended to be CPU intensive, and as the other answer stated, Terasort is I/O intensive.

You should check out [HiBench](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench), which is a Hadoop benchmark suite by Intel.

HiBench uses many existing Hadoop benchmarks and includes preparation scripts for benchmarks like Wordcount (or Terasort), since those benchmarks require that input data be generated first.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop has a [Terasort](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html) benchmark bundled in examples package. It's mostly IO-intensive and may suit your needs well.